# How to URL rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not familiar with url rewrite at all, so I have probably simple question for somebody that knows.

```
<a href="/category.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row['name']));?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a>
```

my url is `http://birthdaycakenames.com/category.php?id=1/all-happy-birthday-cake`
and i want to like this 
`http://birthdaycakenames.com/category/1/all-happy-birthday-cake`
 here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.birthdaycakenames.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://birthdaycakenames.com/$1 [L,R=301]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteRule ^/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/$ category.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?title=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?id=$1&id=$2

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.birthdaycakenames.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://birthdaycakenames.com/$1 [L,R=301]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteRule ^/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/$ category.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?title=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&name=$2

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: try this and rewrite url `http://birthdaycakenames.com/category/1/all-happy-birthday-cake`

Answer (score 0):

This rule definition does not make much sense: you use two back references (`$1` and `&2`) but have only one capture bracket pair in your regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?id=$1&id=$2
```

Have a try like that instead:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

Question here is if you need the name (the value the second back reference resolves to) at all. Since typically a script prefers to operate on an ID instead. If that argument is not required, then you can simply remove it from the target specification of the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/? category.php?id=$1
```

---

A general note: actually the URL you currently generate within php is invalid. A query string like `id=1/all-happy-birthday-cake` is invalid, you'd have to either escape the slash (`/`) in there or specify the name as a second, separate argument: `http://birthdaycakenames.com/category.php?id=1&name=all-happy-birthday-cake`

---

You probably also want to add a `QSA` flag to that rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://birthdaycakenames.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

---

Apart from that I am not sure if that is really what you want: `RewriteRule ^category/$ category.php`, since that means the script `category.php` will get called without any arguments. That might be fine, for example if that script is able to work without to present a list of available categories or similar. But it is not exactly typical.

Comment: i updated it but now its redirectio to http://birthdaycakenames.com/category/1/index.php

Comment: i also update RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/? category.php?id=$1
but again redirecting http://birthdaycakenames.com/category/1/all-happy-birthday-cake to http://birthdaycakenames.com/category/1/index.php

Comment: Remove that rule as also mentioned above: `RewriteRule ^category/$ category.php`

Comment: can you reply full code with php and .htaccess so i easyly update that.

Comment: ok i removed it RewriteRule ^category/$ category.php but still same

Comment: You also want to move that "category.php rule" up so that is comes before the two `details.php rules". Those are more general, so the specific one should be evaluated first.

Comment: This somehow smells as if currently no rewriting at all is performed and only the index module modifies the request if the physical location `/category/1` actually exists as a folder inside your file system (which should not be the case). If so I would expect that you receive some error in your http servers error log file. Could you please check that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107647/discussion-between-sagar-kumar-and-arkascha).

Comment: Sure, let's have a try, happy to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

To change  `http://birthdaycakenames.com/category.php?id=1/all-happy-birthday-cake` **to**
 `http://birthdaycakenames.com/category/1/all-happy-birthday-cake` you need the following 2 Rules :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category\.php\?id=([^/]+)/([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /category.php?id=$1/$2 [NC,L]
```